# What IDE has better support for groovy, Netbeans or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide, groovy

What IDE has better support for groovy, Netbeans or Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last additions to Eclipse integration with Groovy added almost everything needed to the old plugin (which lacked some features) so my points go to Eclipse.

Now the plugin is quite mature and updated very often (3 days ago last update). Key features taken from [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin):

- Syntax highlighting
- Type inferencing
- Compile and run Groovy classes and scripts in Eclipse
- Outline view for Groovy files
- Auto-completion
- Refactoring
- Source code formatting
- Basic debug support

Comment: Yep - the first version of the eclipse plugin about 2 years ago was truly awful, but it's come a long way.

Comment: Yes, I like how you can run in Eclipse as a console , and unlike the default Groovy console, if you have System.in prompting occurring, it will work interactively from within Eclipse.  No more working in a DOS shell!

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Eclipse

### Longer answer

The [Groovy-Eclipse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) plugin used to be unspeakably awful, but it has improved out of all recognition since version 2.X. If you want Grails (rather than just Groovy) support, the simplest option is to install the [SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), which supports Groovy, Grails and lots of other products under the Spring portfolio.

Comment: I assume STS itself uses the Groovy-Eclipse plugin?