# Error: What's wrong with this Groovy code?

Tags: groovy

What's wrong with this Groovy code?

```
class Pretending {
    public int count=0
    Object get(String name)
    {
        return 'hi'
    }
    void set(String name, Object value)
    {
        count++;
    }
    def anto = new Pretending();
```

Here I'm trying to extend the functionality of Groovy set/get method, but when I try to execute this script by `groovy Pret` (where my file name is Pret), I'm getting an error on the last line stating **unexpected token**. What's the reason for this? I'm a newbie to the Groovy world, so I wasn't able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Pretending {
  public int count=55
  Object get(String name) {
    'hi'
  }
  void set(String name,Object value) {
    count++;
  }
}
a = new Pretending()

assert a.any_undef_var == 'hi'
assert a.count == 55
assert a.@count == 55
a.set "v", 4
assert a.count == 56
```

i think this is what you are trying to achieve + extras

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace.  Try:

```
 class Pretending {
   public int count=0
   Object get(String name)
   {
      return 'hi'
   }
   void set(String name,Object value)
   {
     count++;
   }
   def anto = new Pretending();
 }
```

Comment: To avoid mistakes like this in the future, and to speed up development in general, consider using an IDE, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434109/what-ide-has-better-support-for-groovy-netbeans-or-eclipse